# A question on being injective of a measure function

Tags: real-analysis

Imagine $\mu$ is a non-atomic measure and $h=\mu([0,x])$.

The equality
$h(x) = h(y)$ implies $μ([x, y]) = 0$ so there is a countable set $D ⊂ supp μ$ such that
$h|_{supp μ \setminus D}$ is injective and $|h^{−1}(y)| = 2$ for any $y ∈ h(D)$.

It's a part of a text I could not understand why there is a countable set that $h$ restricted to $supp \mu \setminus D$ is injective. Any help?